# IOS stretches an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

I have a logo on my website. The code is as follows:

```css
footer .logo {
  margin: 1px auto 26px auto;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="footer" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <img class="logo" src="logo.png">
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- more content here -->
</footer>
```

For the sake of the question, I'm replacing the logo with a banana.

It looks good on desktop, android and simulated ios devices:
[what the image should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfjMx.png)
But something happens in real ios devices that does not happen in the simulators: 
[what it looks like on an actual ios device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUeFM.png)

It appears that on an IOS device the image is somehow enlarged and then compressed into the width of 150px. Strangely this is the only image that behaves like this from all the images on the website.

Do you know what might be causing this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try with `max-width`

```
footer .logo {
  margin: 1px auto 26px auto;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that `div.row` was the culprit as it had `display: flex`. Changing to `display: block` fixed it.